# Find all files that name start with "Pep" and copy to existing files

Tags: bash, macos

Find all files that names start with **Pep**
(for example PepExample.txt or PepFirst.txt)  and  **COPY**(NOW Rename and Remove) to   **existing** files have names  Example.txt , First.txt.(except files that start with Pep)

PepExample=> copy to Example.txt

PepFirst=> copy to First.txt
and so forth

Comment: What is your question? Please share what you already have tried and what goes wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#! /bin/bash

find . -name 'Pep*' |
    while read path_to_file
    do
        cp "$path_to_file" "$(dirname "$path_to_file")/${path_to_file#*Pep}"
    done
```

This should work pretty well I believe and checks all subdirectories too.

Comment: "*`should work pretty well`*" … as long as the paths do not contain backslashes and linebreaks (I think this assumption is fine) and no directory in the path contains the substring `Pep` (I think this could happen and cause problems).

Answer (score 3):

Use a loop and copy each file individually. To compute the new name you can use `sed` or bash's built-in parameter expansion.

Both of the following scripts assume that you don't have any directories starting with `Pep`.

The following script copies each file starting with `Pep` in the working directory. The new names will have the first `Pep` removed. The `-n` option avoids accidentally overwriting of files.

```
for f in Pep*; done
    cp -n "$f" "${f#Pep}"
done
```

To include sub-directories you can use bash's globstar built-in.

```
shopt -s globstar nullglob
for f in ./path/to/main/dir/**/Pep*; do
    cp -n "$f" "${f//\/Pep/}"
done
```

Always start the path with `./` or `/` so that the script can distinguish between `Pep` at the start of a filename and `Pep` inside a filename, for instance `Pep do not replace Pep in the middle.txt`.

And here's an equivalent script that should work in every POSIX shell, including ancient bash versions as the one on Macs.

```
find path/to/your/main/directory -type f -name Pep\* -exec sh -c \
'echo cp -n "$0" "$(printf %s "$0" | sed -E "s:(.*/)Pep:\1:")"' {} \;
```

Comment: I understand, but I need to copy and not rename

Comment: @D.Rude Sorry. Fixed it.

Comment: It works, but how to set the path to the Main Folder in which the script should do this? in my case it looks like this:
     Main Folder => Example Folder (PepExample.txt and Example.txt) and First Folder (PepFirst.txt and First.txt)

Comment: @D.Rude Right know the script can only handle one directory. You can select the directory by a doing a `cd youDir` first. Do you want to include sub-directories?

Comment: Yes. I want to include sub directories

Comment: Terminal log: man shopt --No manual entry for shopt. Without "shopt"
MacBook:PepMain Rude$ ./script.sh
cp: /Users/Rude/Desktop/PepMain/QQ/**/Pep*: No such file or directory
Directories :
MacBook:PepMain Rude$ ls
PepMain.txt QQ  script.sh
MacBook:PepMain Rude$ cd QQ
MacBook:QQ Rude$ ls
PepFlow.txt

Comment: Oh, didn't know you where using a Mac. Mac's have a highly outdated bash version. I think its from 2007 (that's 12 years ago!) or so. I added yet another solution that should work for you. By the way: Since `shopt` is a built-in it's not `man shopt` but `help shopt` or `info bash` (search for `4.3.2 The Shopt Builtin`).

Comment: find: -execute: unknown primary or operator

Comment: @D.Rude Oops... it's just `-exec`. Fixed it.